# How to increase screen resolution on OSX VM for Parallels?

Tags: macos, parallels

I used Parallels 7 on my macbook to create a osx vm with the restore image, and that worked fine, the only problem is that I can't seem to be able to change the screen size, which magically seems to work with my windows VMs

Any idea what I need to do to change the screen resolution? I would love to be able to do full screen with a proper resolution..

Comment: I'm wondering if Parallels 10 fixes this issue now?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Lion then full screen is obtained by clicking the arrows in the top right hand corner of the window.  Which is true of all windows in Lion, it pops you into a separate desktop and a two finger swipe will get you back to the OS X desktop.  Quite nice, I don't use the coherence mode any more because of that.

Typically, when you can't resize windows etc. that is an indication that the Parallels tools are not installed or are incorrectly installed.  I've had success in the past of un-installing and reinstalling.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. I have no problem switching to full screen mode, but it still scales the same 1024x768 resolution of my OSX 10.9 VM in Parallels. I also have experience with running Windows on Parallels and having the resolution magically adjust to the Parallels window size.